# Hitting token error exception unexpectedly?

Tags: javascript

I am getting unexpected token error from below code and not sure which part have gone wrong

```js
<script>

  function delete(n){

    alert("This is Called");

    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {

      $.ajax({
        url: 'functions/delete.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: n},
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          alert('This Works');

        }
      });

    } else {

    }

  }

</script>
```

Comment: It's because you're including `<script>` tag in an external JavaScript file.

Comment: Also you can't name your function `delete` as that's a reserved word in the JavaScript lexicon.

Comment: For future reference, you've omitted the most important part of the error: the unexpected token. Ie, `Unexpected token` **`<`**, or `Unexpected token` **`)`**.

Answer (score 0):

Re-name your function and get rid of the `<script>` tag if the code is in an external script. Check out below for example:

```js
function deleteFn() {
  alert("This is Called");
  if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    alert('This Works');
    //Make AJAX call here
  }
}

deleteFn();
```

Answer (score -1):

it looks like **delete** is reserved word in JavaScript, try to rename it.

And I would split the code on small peaces and test them separately.

Here is a working example (https://next.plnkr.co/edit/BwG70k3cNQf9sy3A) and the same code below. It does the same as you wanted but without alerts and confirm popups, and I put different URL, it returns response:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

<button onclick="remove('7')">Run POST Request</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<pre id="data"></pre>
    <script>
      function remove(n){
          $.ajax({
            url: 'https://httpbin.org/post',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id: n},
            success: function(response) {
              //console.log(response);
              $('#result').html('POST request was successfull:');
              $('#data').html(JSON.stringify(response, null, '\t'));
            }
          });
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```